# What are the limits as $k \rightarrow \infty $ (the steady states) of the following

Tags: linear-algebra

$a)
\begin{bmatrix}
.4 &.2 \\
.6  &.8 
\end{bmatrix}^{k}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

$b)
\begin{bmatrix}
.4 &.2 \\
.6  &.8 
\end{bmatrix}^{k}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

$c)
\begin{bmatrix}
.4 &.2 \\
.6  &.8 
\end{bmatrix}^{k}$

I'm inclined to say that the answers to these are all the zero matrix, but I feel that is not right. I thought since any fraction less than $1$ will go to $0$ as $k$ approaches infinity. I feel as though I'm not understanding the problem right. Could someone enlighten me on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, diagonalize your matrix (refer to any standard linear algebra textbook). You'll find that with $A=PDP^{-1}$, we may write $A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$. Then, any eigenvalues $|\lambda|<1$ will vanish as $k\to\infty$. If you diagonalize your matrix, you'll find an eigenvalue of 0.2 and 1 -- $D^k$ in this case will approach $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.